# Having enough free memory but getting "Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map"

Tags: java, memory, centos, virtual-machine

My java app crashed after running for 3 days with following information:

```
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 12288 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2627), pid=99975, tid=139586429245184
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_71-b15) (build 1.8.0_71-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.71-b15 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)

/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:       65949688 kB
MemFree:         5425348 kB
Buffers:          772908 kB
Cached:         39944288 kB
SwapCached:         2516 kB
Active:         43029364 kB
Inactive:       13286372 kB
Active(anon):   15486952 kB
Inactive(anon):   114364 kB
Active(file):   27542412 kB
Inactive(file): 13172008 kB
```

I don't understand why it's running out of memory. I set -Xmx16G.
My understanding is, available memory = free + cached, so it should have plenty of available memory, right?
The app is running in a VM. I read on this link's answer that caching only works well on real machine, is it true?
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/command-to-check-process-taking-high-cached-memory-927756/

Any other possibilities on why is this happening?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: On my case it was caused by too many threads, so the fix was just reduce the number of spawned threads.